# Append new data into another sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to append new range of data from CopySheet to Master5 by using the following code, it needs to be appended on the existing data in Master5. I tried using the `getlastrow` function, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
function copysheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A4:R330').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master5'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1.activate()
  spreadsheet.getRange('CopySheet!A4:R330').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('CopySheet'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:330').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, commentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seems to work"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1.activate()` is not a valid request

Only a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) can be [activated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate).

If you want to activate a cell under the last row,

- first you need to chose not only a row, but also a column
- second in a request of type `x+y.activate()` the method (in this case `activate()`) applies only to `y`. In order to apply a method to `x` and `y`, the correct syntax would be `(x+y).activate()`.

**Summary:**

Change

`spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1.activate()`

to

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Chose the name of the sheet from which you want to retrieve the last row");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).activate();
```